# How do I add chosen values of radio buttons by group names in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a survey that contains 47 groups of radio buttons. Each group has 4 radio buttons. Only one can be chosen. I am wanting to add up the chosen values and produce a sum.I have already set the values of the radio buttons. I just need help on selecting the values and adding them up.

I have never done this before and would like an idea or help in the general direction of how to do this. please. thank you

**Sample code below**

```html
<div class="questionDiv" id="Question1"> <!--This ID will need to change for each question-->
  <div class="questionTextDiv">
    <p>1. how hard are you finding this.</p>
  </div> <!--End of questionTextDiv-->
  <div class="radioButtonDiv">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="group1" value="0" /> <!--The group number will also need to change to the same number as questionID-->
    <label for="radio1">Never</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="group1" value="1" />
    <label for="radio2">Sometimes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="group1" value="2" />
    <label for="radio3">Often</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="group1" value="3" />
    <label for="radio4">Always</label>
  </div> <!--End of radioButtonDiv-->
</div> <!--End of questionDiv-->
<hr />
<div class="questionDiv" id="Question2"> <!--This ID will need to change for each question-->
  <div class="questionTextDiv">
    <p>2. when do you get hungry.</p>
  </div> <!--End of questionTextDiv-->
  <div class="radioButtonDiv">
    <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="group2" value="0" />     <!--The group number will also need to change to the same number as questionID-->
    <label for="radio5">Never</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio6" name="group2" value="1" />
    <label for="radio6">Sometimes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio7" name="group2" value="2" />
    <label for="radio7">Often</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio8" name="group2" value="3" />
    <label for="radio8">Always</label>
  </div> <!--End of radioButtonDiv-->
</div> <!--End of questionDiv-->
```

Comment: What is the deal with `c#`?

Comment: @MoshFeu i have no idea how to add the values of these grouped radio buttons

Comment: `add the values` to where? I can show you how to show the selected value of each group. Then, you can send it to the server via `ajax` or something.

Comment: @MoshFeu That sounds good, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that using [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var values = $('.question-wrapper input').serialize();
  alert(values);
  // then send it via ajax like
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your_handler',
    data: values,
    method: 'post'
    // so on
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question-wrapper">
  <div class="questionDiv" id="Question1"> <!--This ID will need to change for each question-->
    <div class="questionTextDiv">
      <p>1. how hard are you finding this.</p>
    </div> <!--End of questionTextDiv-->
    <div class="radioButtonDiv">
      <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="group1" value="0" /> <!--The group number will also need to change to the same number as questionID-->
      <label for="radio1">Never</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="group1" value="1" />
      <label for="radio2">Sometimes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="group1" value="2" />
      <label for="radio3">Often</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="group1" value="3" />
      <label for="radio4">Always</label>
    </div> <!--End of radioButtonDiv-->
  </div> <!--End of questionDiv-->
  <hr />
  <div class="questionDiv" id="Question2"> <!--This ID will need to change for each question-->
    <div class="questionTextDiv">
      <p>2. when do you get hungry.</p>
    </div> <!--End of questionTextDiv-->
    <div class="radioButtonDiv">
      <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="group2" value="0" />     <!--The group number will also need to change to the same number as questionID-->
      <label for="radio5">Never</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio6" name="group2" value="1" />
      <label for="radio6">Sometimes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio7" name="group2" value="2" />
      <label for="radio7">Often</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio8" name="group2" value="3" />
      <label for="radio8">Always</label>
    </div> <!--End of radioButtonDiv-->
  </div> <!--End of questionDiv-->
  <button>Show Values</button>
</div>
```